# AJAX delaying the execution of next lines

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Given the following code, can anyone help me understand why the first alert is executed after the second one? I believe this happens because ajax has a small delay untill it fetches the data, correct me if i am wrong.Thanks in advance.

> Javascript code:

```
window.onload = function() {
arry = new Array();
jQuery.ajax({    
    type: "GET",
    url: "index.php?op=17&id=@@postID@@&action=fetch",   
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(response){    
        var e = response;
        console.log(JSON.parse(e));
        arry = JSON.parse(e)
        alert(e); //1st alert
    }
}); 
alert("test") //2nd alert
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The first "A" in AJAX stands for asynchronous. That means that it is not blocking in your code, so the `alert('test')` is called immediately after your AJAX request, whereas `alert(e)` is only called once the AJAX request has received a successful response from the server.

The 'small delay' that you mention is not such, but rather the time it takes for the server to execute whatever code and return a response.

If you absolutely need the request to be handled synchronously, you can pass the `async` property to the AJAX call as follows:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var arry = [ ];

   jQuery.ajax({    
       type: "GET",
        url: "index.php?op=17&id=@@postID@@&action=fetch",   
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
    }).done(function(response) {
        arry = response
        alert(response); //1st alert
    });

    alert("test") //2nd alert
}
```

Notice that I have updated the code somewhat to use the `done()` promise. Also, specifying `dataType: "json"` negates the need to call `JSON.parse()` on the response text.

Comment: Thanks, but what can i do to fix that?

Comment: See the edited answer, specifically the use of `async: false`.

Comment: Concerning the snippet: *Don't do this! Ever!*

Comment: @JonasW. Do you mean the use of `async: false`?

Answer (score 0):

yous first array is inside the success event of the `AJAX` call which (the success function) gets registered, skipped and called back only when the response of the `ajax` call is ready..

Comment: Please upvote existing answers, instead of posting new ones.

Comment: i just wanted to point out that the success function is part of the Ajax code rather than a code block under it that gets delayed by the AJAX code.